# Website Malware Checker Results

Tags: html, malware

Recently I scanned website for Malware Check and the result was as below :

[image]

Payload showed the below code :

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px;">
                        <span id="xxx" class="xxx">...</span>
                    </div>
```

I was afraid,but later had a look into spam check details from google webmaster tools I got the following result :

[image]

What could be the possible work-around for this solution?

Comment: Use a different advertisement provider, or contact them about the issue to have them fix it.

Comment: put other spam checkers dont show that result !

Comment: It may be a false negative, If you want your site to appear on their search engine Google have you by the balls. You have to play by their rules.

Comment: Why is that `<div>` positioned in such a fashion - what does it contain? Do you recognise it?

Comment: You'd be better off asking on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.